# how to know if a specific socket in open in socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am just starting with socket.io and node.js. I have some code for sending a message to a specific client:

```
io.sockets.sockets[receiverssocket2].emit('message',
{"source": sendersusername,
"message": msg.message,
"target": msg.target});
```

I get the receivers socket id from a pgsql server. Sometimes it takes a bit long to update, so when a user disconnects receiverssocket2 still exists and a message is emitted to the particular socket id, which gives an error as the socket does not exist.
Is there a way i can check if the socket id exists and then emit the message?
I can get a list of connected sockets and check if it exists in the array, but that might take time.

Comment: why are you storing socket ids in database?

Comment: i have 2 socket ids(2 devices) per username and i have two access the socket id from somewhere else too

Comment: An easier design would just be for each connected device to ask the server for information, and then you can reply. If a device isn't connected, it won't ask. To answer your question, you can't know if sockets are open or not.

Comment: I just did it without checking the database.. thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

Well, If your clients are connected to a specific room then you can retrieve an array of clients like this:

```
io.sockets.clients('room');
```

And you can get an array of all rooms by this:

```
io.sockets.manager.rooms;
```